# Separate a class-Diagram into two parts - UML

Tags: web-applications, uml, class-diagram, mobile-application

I'm developing a mobile application which contains a web part for the administration, i'm still preparing the class-diagram, i'm not pretty sure if i have to separate the class-diagram into two parts(a part for the mobile app and a part for the web app) or no. And if i have to separate them what should i do with the relations between the classes in the first part and in the second part.

Comment: Why would there be relationships between classes that belong to two different entities in runtime? Unless you're using some framework that exposes the classes over the network, the classes in the two applications do not interact with each other. Or, if you have a set of common classes that are used in both applications, you should show that. Boundaries work as @Thomas Kilian suggests, as long as there aren't too many classes in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a boundary around the classes for client and server.

The relation between both would likely just be dependencies. You can draw them "as usual". You might attach your drawing to the question for a review.